# Angular2 server

Tags: javascript, angular2

есть SPA приложение на angular2 , на локальном все работает , через BrowserSync , как выложить правильно на домен ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для начала если вы используете `angular-cli` вам необходимо в директории вашего проекта выполнить команду `ng build --prod` данная команда соберет ваш проект, и в директории с проектом появится папка `dist` - это ваш готовый, собранный проект для продакшена.
Далее, есть несколько вариантов.

### 1.Если вы выкладываете на хостинг

Вам необходимо залить содержимое вашей папки `dist` на хостинг, содержимое данной папки чистейшая статика, по этому конфигурируя ваш веб сервер указывайте что это будет статический веб сервер. Но в данном подходе есть минусы:

- Во первых если вы используете пути типа `http://mydomain.ru/route1`
  при обновлении страницы в браузере веб сервер выдаст вам ошибку,
  потому что фактически веб сервер не чего не знает о данном маршруте
  т.к. вы создали статический веб сервер.
- Что бы избежать такого поведения вы можете [подключить](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/common/index/HashLocationStrategy-class.html) в вашем `AppModule` `HashLocationStrategy`, но и здесь есть подводные камни. Ваши маршруты приобретут следующий вид `http://mydomain.ru/#/route1`, таким образом могут возникнуть проблемы с SEO продвижением сайта, если вас это не беспокоит то можете смело использовать этот вариант.

### 2.Если вы выкладываете на VPS сервер

Здесь все проще, и все очень похоже, заливаете на сервер содержимое папки `dist`, и конфигурируете ваш веб сервер, пример конфига для Nginx:

```
server {
 root /var/www/mysite/; #or whereever your site files are
 index index.html;

 location /{
  try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
 }
}
```